# Fort bicycles company from Czech Republic: Where are the steel frames? Company renamed?

Tags: frames, fork

There is or was a company from Czech Republic that produced steel frames and forks. The name of this company is or was **Fort**.

- Why can’t I find anything about this company or their steel frames and forks?
- Where can I buy them?
- Where are the specs?
- Where is the companies website?
- Do they still exist or did they change their name?

I tried to contact (via email) the assumed company website that can be found via search engines, but I got an error mail from `Mail Delivery System` which states that

```
edward@fortbicycles.com (ultimately generated from info@fortbicycles.com)
"No Such User Here"
```

So I still hope somebody here may know which one is the real company that formerly built steel forks and frames. And how I could contact with them.

[fortbicycles.com](http://fortbicycles.com) is **only** a vendor in nothern America and not the manufacturer’s website.

Comment: [This](http://fortbicycles.com/) seems to be their website.  It was the first result on Google when I searched for "Fort bikes".

Comment: This question would be better answered by contacting the company. Kibbee's comment has a link to the company website.

Comment: @Neil Fein could you please unhold this question? Or convert my comment above into an answer?

Comment: @Gary.Ray could you please unhold this question? Or convert my comment above into an answer?

Comment: @erik - I'm not a moderator, so no. I can't. But why can't you just type it into an answer field yourself?

Comment: @Neil Fein now that this question isn’t anymore on “hold” I can answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question, as I have investigated and found some interesting facts. The vendor name for the **Fort steel frames** since the **year 2008** is **Intec**. Search for **Intec**, and you will find all the old frames. In [this forum thread](http://rad-forum.de/topics/412425) user *verreweg* explains the differences since the *renaming* (the manufacturer’s name is still **Fort**): The new frames are *cavity sealed*, have a chemical pre-treatment with phosphates ([*phosphated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphating)) and new stickers with the Intec label.